# Image from MemoryStream in Xamarin.Forms is empty

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my app image must is being opened from byte array. But component "Image" can't opening it. He is empty.

```
public OpenImage (byte[] bin)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            Image image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bin)) };

            this.Content = image;
        }
```

Comment: are you sure that bin is not null and contains valid image data?  And why are you calling InitializeComponent?  This is only needed in a page constructor.

Comment: I'm sure bin not null

Comment: @Jason this seems to be his constructor if you look closely there are no return types to his method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact in my application wrong has been converting data from JSON. Need to will change

```
byte[] bin = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
```

to

```
byte[] bin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would you do it like below:

```
 var imgSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bin));       
  Image myImage =new Image { Source =imgSource };
   This.Content=myImage;
```

See to it that bin is not null and also that it has an image as bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer